# Нужно добавить множество шаров с помощью цикла for

Tags: javascript, canvas, циклы

Нужна помощь в дублировании шариков в `canvas`, я предполагаю, что эту задачу можно выполнить с помощью цикла `for`, но не понимаю, как он должен работать.

```js
var Ball = function(){
 this.x = 100;
 this.y = 100;
 this.xSpeed = -2;
 this.ySpeed = 3;
}
var circle = function(x,y,radius,fillCircle){
 xcl.beginPath();
 xcl.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
 if(fillCircle){
  xcl.fill();
 }else{
  xcl.stroke();
 }
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
 circle(this.x,this.y,8,true);
}
Ball.prototype.speed = function(){
 this.x += this.xSpeed;
 this.y += this.ySpeed;
}
Ball.prototype.otskok = function(){
 if(this.x < 0 || this.x > 200){
  this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
 }
 if(this.y < 0 || this.y > 200){
  this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
 }
}
var obg = [];
for(var i = 0; i < obg.length; i++){
 obg[i] = ball.draw() * 10;
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var xcl = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ball = new Ball();
setInterval(function(){
 xcl.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
 ball.draw();
 ball.speed();
 ball.otskok();
 xcl.strokeRect(0,0,200,200);
},20);
```

```css
#canvas{
 width: 200;
 height: 200;
 border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hello js)!</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "200" height = "200">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src = "js/style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Ball = function(){
 this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
 this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
 this.xSpeed = Math.random() * 6;
  this.ySpeed = Math.sqrt(36 - this.xSpeed*this.xSpeed);
    this.xSpeed = this.xSpeed - 3;
    this.ySpeed = this.ySpeed - 3;
}
var circle = function(x,y,radius,fillCircle){
 xcl.beginPath();
 xcl.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
 if(fillCircle){
  xcl.fill();
 }else{
  xcl.stroke();
 }
}
Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
 circle(this.x,this.y,4,true);
}
Ball.prototype.speed = function(){
 this.x += this.xSpeed;
 this.y += this.ySpeed;
}
Ball.prototype.otskok = function(){
 if(this.x < 0 || this.x > 200){
  this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
 }
 if(this.y < 0 || this.y > 200){
  this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
 }
}
var obg = [];
//for(var i = 0; i < obg.length; i++){
// obg[i] = ball.draw() * 10;
//}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.onclick = ThrowNewBall;
var xcl = canvas.getContext("2d");
function ThrowNewBall() {
  var ball = new Ball();
  obg.push(ball);
}
ThrowNewBall();

setInterval(function(){
 xcl.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    for(var i = 0; i < obg.length; i++) {
   obg[i].draw();
   obg[i].speed();
   obg[i].otskok();
    }
 xcl.strokeRect(0,0,200,200);
},20);
```

```css
#canvas{
 width: 200;
 height: 200;
 border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hello js)!</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "200" height = "200">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src = "js/style.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```